# I have created a application in vb.net with wmp in it and i use panels to clear and add new UC's when i add new UCs my video is played in bg

Tags: vb.net, windows-media-player, axwindowsmediaplayer

```
 Me.Panel1.Controls.Clear()
Dim newV As New LinkTextwithVideo
    Me.Panel1.Controls.Add(newV)
```

This is the code i used to add and remove UCs in form

so, the application is like a computer based training module where each User control form has different contents and video(which is played in Windows media player), i have used me.panel1.controls.clear to remove UCs and change to new UCs but while changing, my videos are running in background

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: so, the application is like a computer based training module where each User control form has different contents and video(which is played in Windows media player), i have used me.panel1.controls.clear to remove UCs and change to new UCs but while changing, my videos are running in background

Comment: `[Control].Controls.Clear()` doesn't *clear* anything, just removes the references from the collection. Your UCs are still very well alive and kicking. You need to call `Dispose()` on them all (with a backwards `For` loop). The internal `Dispose([boolean])` method must dispose of all managed (when required) and unmanaged resources it uses.